# using 2 seekbars in the same activity

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I have 2 seekbars A and B and i have 2 textviews C and D. A edits the value of C when moved and B edits the value of D when moved. My code works fine. However I want it so that when the user is using A then seekbar B becomes disabled and likewise when seekbar B is being used by the user A becomes disabled. The way the seekbars become undisabled is when a user clicks on it to use it again. So if i were using seekbar A then B would be disabled then if i touched seekbar B it would be enabled and then A would be disabled. Or even if it ment changing the seekbars colour which is blue at the moment to a light grey colour to give the illusion that it is disabled would be another way perhaps. Neway i tried this.
 for seekbar A

```
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             seekbarB.setEnabled(false);
             seekbarA.setEnabled(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             seekbarB.setEnabled(true);
             seekbarA.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

and for seekbar B

```
@Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             seekbarB.setEnabled(true);
             //seekbarA.setEnabled(false);

        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekbar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             seekbarB.setEnabled(true);
             seekbarA.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

but however this kind of worked but then when the user stopped using either of the seekbars the one that had been disabled became enabled again which I didnt want unless the user touched it. Now i know what your thinking dont set the seekbars to enabled in the onstoptrackingtouch. Well i tried that and the seekbar that was disabled would never become enabled even if you touched it i even implemented an ontouchlistener for each seekbar to see if it would become active but it didnt.
so i have three ways of you guys helping me.
1. Is there a way to edit my method above to get it working the way i want?
2. Where can i put my enable seekbar method so that the seekbar only becomes active when the user touches it thus achieving what i stated above?
3. Is there a way to change a custom seekbars colours in java to achieve what i want

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following: put the `SeekBar` in a `Layout` that wrap the `SeekBar` and put a `OnTouchListener` on the `Layout`, then re-enable the `SeekBar` when the user touches the `Layout`.

The color of the `SeekBar` cannot be easily changed afaik (you need to create colored resources, see [this site](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to generate such resouces).

If you want to communicate to the user that he can only use one `SeekBar` at a time, I would, instead of using

```
seekbar.setEnabled(false)
```

just reduce the alpha of the `SeekBar`, making it 'pale'. Use `seekBar.setAlpha()` or, if you want to target API levels < 11, use [this library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids)'s ViewHelper class.